# Efficient way to remove struct based on one member, but chose which one to keep by other member

Tags: c++

I have a vecor `list` of found WiFi networks. Problem is, it detects all transmitters, even if they have the same name (repeaters). I want to delete the duplicates, but keep the one with highest quality (RSSI).

```
Example:
{HomeWiFi, -60}
{HomeWiFi, -55}
{HomeWifi, -80}    //Worse signal, duplicate name = repeater further away
{AnotherWifi, -70}

Expected output:
{HomeWiFi, -55}
{AnotherWifi, -70}
```

I was thinking of sorting them by name and then deleting consecutive duplicates with `std::unique`, but I don't know how to specfy the "secondary" sorting by quality.

```cpp
struct WiFiParam
{
    String SSID;
    int32_t RSSI; 
    .....
};

std::vector<WiFiParam> list;
```

Comment: Pass a lambda to `sort` to sort it on your own conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With custom functor, you might do:

```
std::vector<WiFiParam> params /*= */;

auto less_by_name_signal = [](const WiFiParam& lhs, const WiFiParam& rhs){
    return std::tie(lhs.SSID, rhs.RSSI) < std::tie(rhs.SSID, lhs.RSSI);
};
std::sort(params.begin(), params.end(), less_by_name_signal);
auto equal_by_name = [](const WiFiParam& lhs, const WiFiParam& rhs){
    return lhs.SSID == rhs.SSID;
};
params.erase(std::unique(params.begin(), params.end(), equal_by_name), params.end());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/E8SS13)

Comment: I am getting some "no matching function for call" errors, not sure what am I missing. Also, doesn't vector.erase remove just one (or range of) members in a vector? I have a problem where I have multiple of duplicated WiFi networks (office area)

Comment: @MarosMacko The call to `std::unique` does not erase elements. It puts all duplicate elements at the back of the vector and returns an iterator to where these duplicate elements begin. So this iterator is then commonly used in a call to `std::vector::erase` to delete all duplicate entries from the vector. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique for more info.

Comment: @MarosMacko: typo fixed (extra `)`) and link added.

Comment: @Jarod42 I spotted and fixed the `)` typo, but somehow it did not like it. Anyway, don't know how, it works now :) Thanks